# OOP Performance after compilation

Tags: oop, compilation, programming-languages, interpreter

I got into a conversation with someone about OOP, who said that OOP costs to much performance. Now I know that in some cases it might, but as I see it, it would depend on different things.

- Language execution. In languages using an interpretor, I can see that it could be a possibility. But what about compiled language like C++ or half compiled like Java? In any case it would just slow down the compilation vs. C, but as native or byte code I would think that the compilers would have optimized it to a point where this is not a problem.
- Language structure. If we take PHP as an example, it is quite a flexible language with little rules. Java on the other hand uses strict naming schemes, strict file structure rules and is strict about data types. This speeds up lookup quite a bit. What if we used the same rules in PHP? Made it 100% OOP and adapted the same rules as Java has, would this not speed up PHP?

I found a really great [OOP example](http://www.sitepoint.com/oop-and-performance/), but this example does not prove the upside of OOP, but rather the upside of overview and structure. It's no problem using PP to do the same, at least not in PHP.

Comment: It is not that easy to optimise out all the unnecessary virtual calls. Mainstream compilers only recently started trying to approach this, with a little luck so far. Read more here: http://hubicka.blogspot.cz/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html

Answer (score 1):

OOP is a *very* moot term and that's why your question is moot as well.

On the most generic level, OOP is about objects (let's not dive into what they are) encapsulating some *state* and passing each other *messages* to enquire or change that state.  As you can see, these objects might be processes running on separate network-connected machines and message passing might be done quite literally—by passing messages of some application-level protocol over that network; this is the one extreme.  The opposite edge of this spectrum is, say, C or C++ or Object Pascal etc which are compiled down to machine instructions and in which objects are just memory regions.  I reckon the only "interesting" topic is a language on this side of the OOP spectrum, right?

In this, down-to-machine, level, the only relevant slow down I perceive is *dynamic dispatch* which is what is typically used to implement implementation inheritance (`class Bar extends class Foo` as in PHP) which allows you to pass objects of derived classes to the code expecting objects of their base class.  This is typically requires a lookup through the table of methods at runtime to select a relevant method.

Note that this is not somehow inherent to the *concept* of OOP.  For instance, dynamic lookup like this has been routinely used in plain C code even before C++ came to existence, and C is not an OOP language.

What I'm leading you to, is that *some ways to access data and code* cost more than others in terms of performance but provide powerful programming tools.  Picking such an algorythm while considering a resulting tradeoff is not at all peculiar to implementing OOP concepts and happens in any computing field and any computing paradigm or a combinations of them.

In the end, I would say that the most visible slow-downs will come not from the code running on a CPU but rather from the runtime system.  For instance, PHP is known for its ability to dynamically load code at runtime.  Does this count as a feature of it being an OOP-enabled language?  On the one hand, in these days of heavy frameworks, when PHP loads something it usually loads definitions of classes.  On the other hand, if these frameworks were, say, purely procedural the same performance cost would be incurred (as the most loading time is spent waiting on I/O).  Interpreted or JIT-compiled languages have to interpret or compile the code they execute and this incurs pefrormance hits.  Does this depend on some of these languages implementing OOP concepts?  Unlikely, IMO.